$int(cl(A)) \subseteq cl(int(cl(A)) \cap A)$
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A,B \subseteq X$.
Show that $int(Cl(A)) \subseteq cl(int(cl(A)) \cap A)$
I am trying to prove the above statement but both of the methods I have tried thus far are leading to dead ends.
Attempt 1:

Let $x \in int(Cl(A))$. This means $\exists r > 0 $ such that $B_{r}(x)\subseteq Cl(A)$. However, this appears to be a dead end because I am not sure how I would use this to show that $x \in cl(int(cl(A)) \cap A) \cup (cl(int(cl(A)) \cap A)'$
Attempt 2:

For this attempt, I used the fact that the closure of a set is always a superset of the set.

So, $int(Cl(A)) \subseteq Cl(int(Cl(A)))$ was my first step, but obviously this is a dead end because of the intersection between $int(Cl(A))$ and $A$.
Any hints or help in general would be appreciated.

It suffices to prove $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A)) \cap A$ is dense in $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A))$, that is, it suffices to prove for any $x \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A))$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $y \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A)) \cap A$ s.t. $d(x, y) < \epsilon$. Now, since $x \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A))$, there exists $\epsilon’ \leq \epsilon$ such that $B(x, \epsilon’) \subset \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A))$. But then because $x \in \mathrm{cl}(A)$, there exists $y \in B(x, \epsilon’) \cap A$. Clearly then $y \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(A)) \cap A$ and $d(x, y) < \epsilon’ \leq \epsilon$, which proves the claim.
